# cannot able to connect/hit endpoint using apikey

Tags: api, postman, ibm-watson

not able to understand why it is not getting connected, passed everything as per documentation why getting Unauthorized, what else can i do
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnqP7.png)

Comment: Add the documentation

Comment: Add details on what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation you should pass this as basic authentication and not api key

Set authentication as basic authentication and set username as apikey and password as  eg djdkkslsllsksmsmz

https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v2

In curl -u indicates username and password basic authentication

Comment: Yes @PDHide, did the same, referred documentation passed it as you said, got the same error...

"error": "No such child resource.",
    "code": 404,
    "code_description": "No Such Resource"
}

Comment: @baruud what ibm watson service are you using , could you add the usecase more clearly

Comment: Tried using curl they way they shared as they said, still got error

Comment: There are different ibm watson services and each uses different authentication could you add more details one what are you trying which endpoint you are hitting

Comment: trying to invoke Speech to Text service; pretty straight forward; but cannot isolate why it is not hitting the API, testing connectivity it before I can integrate it to Outsystems app

endpoint: https://api.eu-gb.speech-to-text.watson.cloud.ibm.com/instances/38ecb2be-b1e5-48b8-b4cf-525e36235339

Comment: https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/account?topic=account-iamtoken_from_apikey

Comment: You have to create an auth token and pass it in postman as bearer

Comment: And also could you try passing api as key and <value>  instead of apikey in header and then as query parameter (from authorization api key in postman)

Comment: retried, earlier used all of these methods that you mentioned; yet getting the same error; passed it as api key as params and header value, tried generating service credential as well with writer access privileges; so even the bearer option did not work

Comment: I am now seriously not sure what IBM has done, something changed and documentation is not updated or what is the case. pulled out all stops on this one using whatever documentation is available